# How to grow a block on each page

Tags: tikz-pgf, eso-pic, everypage

I would love to have a solid box on the right side of each page showing the manually set category of that page. That works so far, but the box is not adjusted / centered correctly and I don't know how to adjust this.

Perfect would be a box on the right side of the page that shows the text and the color grading box is surrounding the text with 0.15cm margin. Right now I set both manually and this is not working well...

My goal is to only change the `pageCategory` and have a solution for my employees to work with^^.

Here what I tried so far. It works, but it is not growing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2in,bottom=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\newcommand{\pageCategory}[1]{\def \varPageCategory {#1}}
\pageCategory{}
\definecolor{MyBlue}{rgb}{0.41,0.2,0.6}
\definecolor{MyRed}{rgb}{0.97,0.2,0.41}

%\usepackage{showframe}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \ifdefempty{\varPageCategory}{}%
    {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
        \draw[white,top color=MyBlue,bottom color=MyRed] ($(current page.east)+(0cm,4cm)$) -- ($(current page.east)+(0cm,8cm)$) -- ($(current page.east)+(-1cm,8cm)$) -- ($(current page.east)+(-1cm,4cm)$) -- ($(current page.east)+(0cm,4cm)$);%
        \node[white,rotate=90, thick, line width=2pt] at ($(current page.east)+(-0.5cm,5cm)$) {\fontsize{10}{12} \varPageCategory};%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \pageCategory{Page One}
    \lipsum
    \pagebreak
    \clearpage
    \pageCategory{Page Two and Three}
    \lipsum
    \pagebreak
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't follow exactly what you wish. But I think it is better to use a single node. You can control the node inner sep, outer sep, filling, sizes and so.

Comment: If you can read HTML it is more or less:

```
<div class="side">This is just a Text</div>
```

Where `div.side` has a color grade from blue to red, is turned 90 degres and put to the right side of the page. Inside of the div is a text with margin so that we see the color grading.

Comment: Do you want a fixed node size or it adjusts according to the text inside it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this clear code could help you to improve and adapt it.

The node anchor is `south` so after rotated it is on the right. You can control the distance to the right paper edge changing the `outer sep` parameter.

The node size depends on its contents, centered.

[image][image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2in,bottom=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\newcommand{\pageCategory}[1]{\def\varPageCategory{#1}}
\pageCategory{}
\definecolor{MyBlue}{rgb}{0.41,0.2,0.6}
\definecolor{MyRed}{rgb}{0.97,0.2,0.41}

\tikzset{%
  mynode/.style={%
    top color=MyBlue,
    bottom color=MyRed,
    white,
    rotate=90,
    draw=black,
    line width=2pt,
    align=center,
    anchor=south,
    font=\fontsize{10}{12},
    inner sep=5pt,
    outer sep=10pt
  }%
}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \ifdefempty{\varPageCategory}{}%
    {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]%
        \node[mynode] at (current page.east) {\varPageCategory};%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \pageCategory{Page One}
    \lipsum
    \pagebreak
    \clearpage
    \pageCategory{Page Two and Three}
    \lipsum
    \pagebreak
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I am now in week two of not just using predefinded templates from my old university but writing my own stuff and I kind of understand more every day and still try a lot out. This helped me especially after 7 hours of tryout...

Thank you so much!

Comment: @BastianBringenberg, welcome. If you need some adjustment, let us know. Node anchors are very useful.